# Adding a stroke to a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton

How do I add a stroke to a UIButton, either in interface builder or programatically? I want to create the same effect that you get in photoshop when you add a stroke to a shape (like an outline)

Comment: Please clarify a little bit – do you mean a graphical stroke? As in, a line or curve of some sort? Do you want to add stroke using a subview, drawing with Core Graphics, or some sort of Core Image effect? Give a little more context about what you have and what you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

use layer.width property of a button,you can give width in float value.button has a property called layer.